# JuPyTer crashes on simple Theano function

Tags: python, function, theano, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I just recently installed python and JuPyTeron a new MacOS and wanted to get into DeepLearning. Therefore, I was looking at Theano.

But when I try to execute a very simple function with Theano in the JuPyTer Notebook, it crashes on me, and I don't get why. Can you please help me?

Here is the code:

```
import theano
from theano import tensor
from theano import function
a = tensor.dscalar()
b = tensor.dscalar()
c = a + b
f = function([a,b], c)
```

I have isolated the error to the last line, when the following message pops up:

[Picture of JuPyTer crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5pBG.png)

Comment: can you please start jupyter from the terminal and see if you can find any further information on the error after a crash?

Comment: Hi @cel, I suppose I could do that, but in the meantime, I figured out, that I better use the bleeding edge developer version of Theano (http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#bleeding-edge-install-instructions) and after a restart of JuPyTer, the theano.test() function passed (with only some warnings) and the function worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing the bleeding edge version of Theano via `sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git` the error vanished. Also, for anyone, who is also trying to troubleshoot their Theano issues: try to run `import theano;theano.test()` and look for the errors and warnings shown.